# How can I undo the reordering of table view cells on the tap of a button

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I am trying to reorder the cells inside my tableView.

```
    //reordering logic starts here
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {

    let item = array[sourceIndexPath.row]
    array.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    array.insert(item, at: destinationIndexPath.row)

}
```

The table view has a cancel button which when tapped should make reset the reordering of the table view cells that was done earlier.

```
@IBAction func cancelButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Multiple Actions", message: "The alert has more than one action which means more than one button.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet)

    let cancelReorder = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { _ in

    }
```

How should I achieve the same in my cancelReorder alert action?

I am new to IOS development and swift.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you can keep a copy of your original array in another and on cancel button assign that 2nd array to your original to get ordered array.

Comment: Use `NSUndoManager` and add the appropriate methods. In iOS shaking the device triggers the undo operation by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check below code:

```
let arrOriginal = ["Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3", "Test 4", "Test 5",]
var arrCopy = [String]()
```

in `viewDidLoad()`

```
arrCopy = arrOriginal
```

on Alert's cancel button:

```
 let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Multiple Actions", message: "The alert has more than one action which means more than one button.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet)

    let cancelReorder = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { _ in

    arrOriginal = arrCopy
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use two arrays, let's say `originalArray` and `currentArray`

```
var originalArray:[String]?
var currentArray:[String]?

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   originalArray = ["1", "2", "3"]
   currentArray = originalArray
}
```

`originalArray` never changes and it has the original values, instead `currentArray` changes with your sorting/filtering, moreover will be the one used by the `UITableViewDataSource`.

So whenever you want to reset the `currentArray` (eg: in the completion of your alert action), you might do so:

```
let cancelReorder = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { _ in
   currentArray = originalArray // reset the current array with the original values
   tableView.reloadData() // this will refresh the table view
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you set masterList and filteList for the view.
filterlist contains the ordered collection of masterlist .When press button should work a logic and insert item from masterList to filterList and reload the tableview.You should set the fileterlist as datasource for the tableview.